# Is there a fast way in Facebook to know what user liked post if this post contains about 3.500.000 likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Post id is 100827133412869_362817400547173. You can see it's so much likes there. I'd like to know is there a faster way to find out what user liked this post? When I used FQL it was this query:"SELECT object_id, post_id, user_id FROM like WHERE user_id = me()". But now FQL isn't available.

I'm trying to use pagination, but with limit=25 it's about 140.000 requests, and you understand how much time it will take. When I use limit=100 it takes about 3-4s(!) for one request! It also takes too much time. None of users will be waiting for 10-15 mins. I can't find another way in your documentation.

Ms iOS SDK version is 3.18, Graph API v.2.1. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: i don´t think it´s possible without going through every like, but why would you need to know anyway? what is the use case?

Comment: With Graph API v2.1 there's no way that I know of to do this without getting all the likes. I agree to @luschn, what's the Use Case?

Comment: Hi! We have an iOS application, that shows FB feed. And there we show him what post user likeв by himself.

Comment: not sure if that is even possible. with authorization you only get an app scoped token, but the like may come with the real user id. if that is the case, you can´t tell if it´s the right user.